# React-router authentication re-fires with increment of 1 on route change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a basic react/react-router-v3 authentication process set up using onEnter={requireAuth} on my routes.

Everything works, the user gets authenticated, the script checks if the user has sufficient rights to the route, and redirects just fine.

If I use any type of route within my application to link to a different component however, the requireAuth function seems to re-fire with an increment of 1 for each time I routed.

**index.js**

```
ReactDOM.render((
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>

        <IndexRoute 
                component={ AuthContainer }
                socket={socket}
        />

        <Route 
                path="/access-denied"    
                component={ AccessDeniedContainer }
                onEnter={() => requireAuth({socket: socket, role: ['admin', 'editor', 'user']})} 
                socket={socket}
        />
        <Route 
                path="/dashboard"    
                component={ DashboardContainer }    
                onEnter={() => requireAuth({socket: socket, role: ['admin', 'editor']})} 
                socket={socket}
        />
        <Route 
                path="/digital-sign" 
                component={ DigitalSignContainer }
                onEnter={() => requireAuth({socket: socket, role: ['admin', 'user']})} 
                socket={socket} 
        />
    </Route>
  </Router>
), document.getElementById('root'));
```

**authService.js**

```
// Checks function if user is logged in
export function requireAuth(authData) {
    console.log('doing auth');
    isLoggedIn(authData);
}

// Gets JWT token from local storage
export function getToken() {
    return localStorage.getItem('jwt');
}

// Checks if a user is logged in && is permitted to see protected routes
export function isLoggedIn(authData) {  
    const validatedToken = getToken();
    const requiredRole = authData.role;

    console.log('checking....');

    var loggedInSocket = authData.socket;

    // Send token to server for validation
    loggedInSocket.emit('authToken', validatedToken); 

    loggedInSocket.on('noToken', function() {
        browserHistory.replace('/');
    });

    // If fake token
    loggedInSocket.on('falseToken', function() {
        browserHistory.replace('/');
    }); 

    // if user validated
    loggedInSocket.on('validated', function(userToken) {
        if( requiredRole.indexOf(userToken.role) > -1 ) {
            console.log('User is:' + userToken.role);
            console.log('Must have:' + requiredRole);
            return validatedToken;
        }
        else {
            console.log('User is:' + userToken.role);
            console.log('Must have:' + requiredRole);
            browserHistory.replace('/access-denied');   
        }           
    });
}
```

The console.log within

> loggedInSocket.on('validated', function(userToken){}

fires just fine when I refresh the browser. If I navigate within my application using routes, it fires twice. When I navigate/route again, it fires three times. Etc. I'm at a loss and don't really know where to start debugging this.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the socket listeners in my components weren't removed on routeChange. I fixed it by removing them when the component unmounts.

```
componentWillUnmount() {
    this.socket.removeListener('showrows');
    this.socket.removeListener('requestGroupId');
    this.socket.removeListener('getData');
}
```